# Run multiple SQL actions in a single procedure

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm still quite new to SQL so pardon bad terminology.

I'm using MSAccess.
I have a pass-through query which I need to use to update a table.
This currently means a 3-query process;

- The pass-through query which gets the original data
- A 'makeTable' query that creates a temporary table from that data (in order to do the below)
- an 'Update' query that puts the data from the temporary table into the main table to be updated.

As my end project is going to be kind of complex, i'd like to combine these queries somehow or other. Does SQL support calling different queries from each other, or writing a procedure that runs through them all? I know it can be done in VBA but kind of wanted to minimise the amount of different queries in my navigation pane.

(This question is as much out of interest as for actual usefulness - any advice appreciated)

Comment: You will have to write a procedure that runs through them all - done in VBA.

Comment: so it's a no-can-do in sql? Guess that answers the question...

Comment: Can minimize queries in navigation pane by running SQL statements constructed in VBA.

Comment: Hey thanks @June7 that's great, I hadn't considered that option! I'll definitely be doing that then.

Comment: Might find this of interest https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc75d7f0-fd6b-439e-a4bc-6fc5f4e94133/access-queries-vs-sql-run-by-vba